# Fewer lines for switch statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I wonder if this …

```
inputs.keydown(function (e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 13:    //Enter
        case 16:    //Shift
        case 17:    //Ctrl
        case 18:    //Alt
        case 19:    //Pause/Break
        case 20:    //Caps Lock
        case 27:    //Escape
        case 35:    //End
        case 36:    //Home
        case 37:    //Left
        case 38:    //Up
        case 39:    //Right
        case 40:    //Down

        // Mac CMD Key
        case 91:    //Safari, Chrome
        case 93:    //Safari, Chrome
        case 224:   //Firefox
        break;
        default:
        $(this).addClass(fill);
        break;
    }
});
```

… is also possible with fewer lines?
I know I could do an if-condition, but I wonder if I missed something like `case 13 && 16 && …`

Maybe some of you know a better practice to check all the cases and write fewer lines of code.
I'm just wondering.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I personally think its better than a series of `OR`s and `AND`s using `if`s (which would be longer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put the codes into an array, and then you can simply check if the value is in the array. Since you are using jQuery, you already have an [`inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method to do this.

```
var keycodes = [13, 16, 17, 18, 19]; //and so on

//if the keycode is not found in the array, the result will be -1
if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, keycodes) === -1) { 
    $(this).addClass(fill);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could create a "map" of the keys you don't want to handle - map lookups should be somewhere between `O(1)` and `O(log n)`, depending on the implementation.

```
var specialKeys = {
    13: 1, // Enter
    16: 1, // Shift
    ...
    224: 1 // Cmd/FF
};

inputs.keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode in specialKeys) return;
    $(this).addClass(fill);
});
```

Alternatively as your "keys" are all integers you could fill an array where the indexes are the key code values.

**EDIT** removed the strings, as suggested by @bažmegakapa

Comment: Still not fewer "lines" of code (neither is mine), but I'm not seeing that as a really useful goal anyway...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder think of the object literal as "data" rather than "code" ;-)

Comment: +1 should be more efficient than mine. The string values feel a bit unnecessary, comments can at least be cut out by the minifier.

Comment: @bažmegakapa true, it could just as well be "1" for the value and then just put the rest in as comments.

Comment: it's a shame there's no way to create a sparse array literal (i.e. where only some of the array indices are prefilled)

Answer (score 2):

What you have is fine. It's clear, and it'll get handled fairly efficiently. Alternately, you can do it with [`Array#indexOf`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.14):

```
var list1 = [
        13,    //Enter
        16,    //Shift
        17,    //Ctrl
        18,    //Alt
        19,    //Pause/Break
        20,    //Caps Lock
        27,    //Escape
        35,    //End
        36,    //Home
        37,    //Left
        38,    //Up
        39,    //Right
        40     //Down
];
var list2 = [
        91,    //Safari, Chrome
        93,    //Safari, Chrome
        224    //Firefox
];
inputs.keydown(function (e) {
    if (list1.indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1) {
        // ...
    }
    else if (list2.indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1) {
        // ...
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass(fill);
    }
});
```

But it's only fewer "lines" of code if you lose the comments, and the comments seem (to me) to be important.

Note that some quite old browsers won't have `Array#indexOf` and so you may have to shim it (which is easy enough to do). Or use `jQuery.inArray` instead, since you're using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's more clear to use the code you pointed out, but for your convenience you can use the conditions inside the case...

```
case (condition):
//code
break;
```

Personally I would put all the possible matches into an array and use [in_array()](http://phpjs.org/functions/in_array:432) from [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org) to check if the value to be tested is there.

Comment: If jQuery is already available, phpjs seems to be overkill for this.

Comment: I'm assuming jQuery is not there ;)